Unable to install android studio: network unreachable
I tried to install Android Studio via  JetBrains Toolbox several times this week. but every time I receive the message shown in the following screenshot. I checked my connection. Even I used some VPNs, but the problem wasn't resolved.


Have you tried uninstalling the toolbox and reinstalling it? Are you logged in? Retry to log in...

Yes I was looged in

I finally downloaded and installed Android Studio stand-alone. when choosing the path for unpacking it, I chose the JetBrains toolbox default folder used for installing the Tools (~/. local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps in Linux). So the toolbox can update Android Studio to the next versions.
